# Android Retrofit library Okhtpp3 issue in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, retrofit2

I'm working on a Eclipse Project, in which I'm using Retrofit Library for REST API call, and  I'm facing "**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:okhttp3.HttpUrl**".***[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlo43.png)***. I have added the needed libraries too ***[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErhUW.png).***
The same project works well in android studio if i add the libraries as a dependency and enable mutidex true.
But in eclipse i'm not getting the solution.

Can anyone hep me out?

Comment: First things first, please do not use Eclipse to do Android Development. Please move to Android Studio, the world moved to Android Studio at least 3 years back. Next, please show the list of libraries you are using

Comment: I can't help, but I can explain why it is bad idea to use eclipse: Because nobody is able to help you, cause none face similar issues because none is using eclipse anymore. You won't be ale to get help about eclipse-specific problems anymore because there is no community who still uses it. Soon or later you will have to move to Android Studio, and sooner you move - less problems you will face.

Comment: I've updated image3 , in which it has the libraries which i used.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'm using android studio only but i need to know whether is there any possibilities of fixing the the issue in eclipse. Please help me out?